# Поиск по сайту

Tags: mysql

Подскажите, есть скрипт поиска, но ищет он только в одном столбце совпадение, а надо, чтобы в двух, что делать?

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users s INNER JOIN categories c ON s.id = c.cid WHERE lname LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%' ORDER BY id LIMIT 8");
```

Он ищет только в ячейке lname, а надо, чтобы ещё и в fname, что нужно исправить? Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Добавить еще одно условие.

Comment: Подскажите, а как его правильно добавить в sql ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`..WHERE условие1 OR условие2`, примерно так:

```
$queryString = addslashes( $queryString); // ещё один презерватив поверх, на всяк

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users s INNER JOIN categories c ON s.id = c.cid ";
$sql .= " WHERE lname LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%' ";
$sql .= " OR fname LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%' ";
$sql .= " ORDER BY id LIMIT 8";
$query = $db->query( $sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

Элементарно:

```
WHERE lname LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%' OR fname LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%'
```

и желательно указывать, к какой таблице относятся столбцы `lname` и `fname`, чтобы не было проблем в случае, если столбцы с такими именами есть в обеих таблицах.