# Поиск по имени и фамилии

Tags: mysql

Подскажите, есть код поиска, он проверяет на совпадение или с одной таблицей или со второй. А как вы заметили, первая таблица fname-Имя Пользователя, а lname-фамилия. Подскажите, как или что дописать к запросу, чтобы можно было вводить в поиск имя "Иван Иванов" и он его нашел, а не только отдельно имя Иван или фамилию Иванов. Заранее спасибо!
Ниже указан код!

```
<?php
        $query = $db->query("SET character_set_connection=utf8");
        $query = $db->query("SET character_set_client=utf8");
        $query = $db->query("SET character_set_results=utf8");
        $query = $db->query("SET NAMES utf8");
        if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
            $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);

            if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
                $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users s INNER JOIN categories c ON s.id = c.cid WHERE (lname LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%' OR fname LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%') OR (lname LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%' AND fname LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%') ORDER BY id LIMIT 8");

                if($query) {

                    $catid = 0;
                    while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                        if($result->id != $catid) { 
                            $catid = $result->d;
                        }
```

Comment: попробуй еще мой вариант

Comment: ну вся проблема и состоит в том что одно поле... или сделайте отдельно поля под имя и фамилию или разбивать строку на два слова если имеется пробел...

Comment: ну тогда допустим у вас
    $_POST['queryString'] == "Ivan Ivanov";

    $flname = explode(" ", $_POST['queryString']);
    $flname[0]; // Ivan
    $flname[1]; // Ivanov

Comment: Спасибо огромное, теперь все работает,но почему то при вводе имени (сейчас 2 пользователя alexander Kilo и Demo Demo) показываются все пользователи а потом когда уже начинается ввод фамилии через пробел то тогда находит конкретного пользователю а можно как нибудь исправить что бы сразу же когда вводилось Alexander он начинал поиска а не после введения + фамилии ?

Comment: после

    $flname = explode(" ", $_POST['queryString']);

вставьте

    if(count($flname) == 1)
    {
    $flname[1] = $flname[0];
    }

Comment: Спасибо,а теперь после того как вводишь пробел между именем и фамилии то появляются все значения а потом все нормально опять,ем это может быть вызвано ?

Comment: При вводе имени пользователя он показывает всех пользователей с этим именем,потом когда вводишь пробел после имени он показывает всех пользователей,а после пробела когда начинаешь вводить фамилию опять показывает пользователя с именем который в начале и фамилией,почему когда пробел показывает всех пользователей ?

Comment: заменить

    $flname = explode(" ", $_POST['queryString']);

на

    $flname = explode(" ", trim($_POST['queryString']));

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users s INNER JOIN categories c ON s.id = c.cid WHERE (lname LIKE '%" . $flname[1] . "%' OR fname LIKE '%" . $flname[0] . "%') OR (lname LIKE '%" . $flname[1] . "%' AND fname LIKE '%" . $flname[0] . "%') ORDER BY id LIMIT 8");
```

Comment: потому что тут кругом один параметр подставляется

Comment: так не видно твоего кода, а и я в пхп несилен =) сделай еще queryString2  в запросе и передавай туда фамилию, тебе же в первом твоем этом вопросе ответили...

Comment: Ответ это который последний вы имеете ввиду там где *WHERE условие1 OR условие2* имели ввиду ?только добавить условие 3 ?

Comment: немного поправил ответ @oneboy, попробуй еще раз его

Comment: теперь вообще не чего не ищет и выдает ошибку что с запросом что то не верно.Посмотрите ещё если вас не затруднит в чем ошибка в ней ?

Comment: покажите ваш php код который у вас перед запросом

Comment: Добавил к описанию вопроса!

Answer (score 1):

[Поиск по сайту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/134661/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%83). Попробуйте еще так:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users s INNER JOIN categories c ON s.id = c.cid WHERE (lname LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%' OR fname LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%')
OR (CONCAT(lname,' ',fname)) LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%' ) ORDER BY id LIMIT 8");
```